# Gradle build tasks says Gradle Wrapper version lower then version defined in Gradle properties

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

In Android Gradle project root I do

```
gradle app:assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

but I get error

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 5.1.

and message says

> try editing the distributionUrl in /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

but `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` is `5.4.1` not `5.1`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

**edit**

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-02 18:57:47 UTC
Revision:     d09c2e354576ac41078c322815cc6db2b66d976e

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.0
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_192 (Oracle Corporation 25.192-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see, I was using the Gradle binary set in the environment and not the gradle wrapper, should be

```
./gradlew app:assembleDebug --stacktrace
```